# Circuit with DRV8825 and PCF8574 not working! Will it be a problem with the components itself?

Tags: i2c, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I'm developing a circuit using a PCF8574 and a DRV8825 to control a step motor.
The PCF8574 is used to control the reset, enable, sleep, modes and read the FAULT line of the DRV8825 using only the two wires from the I2C protocol.

The step and the direction line from the DRV8825 are hard-wired.

Here is the circuit:

[image]

However, this circuit is not working as expected. I can observe the following behaviors:

1. Not all the PCF8574 outputs are going to HIGH state when I send the command through the I2C protocol
2. Some outputs from the PCF8574 have a voltage below the 5V (the logic power) when are set to HIGH state. Something around 1.7V and 2.2V
3. Sometimes I can observe a kind of short circuit near to the pins 12 and 13 (VREF) of the DRV8825 when I change the value of the trimpot. I can confirm there's nothing wrong with the board (I mean, traces are not short-circuited to the ground or other signals).
4. The DRV8825 are going to be hot very very fast even there's no motor movement.
5. The DRV8825 (when it's "working") is moving the motor randomly in a weird way even I don't send any commands.

Can you guys give me your opinion about this board? What must it be?

**It's very important to say that both the PCF8574 and the DRV8825 were desoldered from other boards**

Will it be a problem with the components? Maybe too much heat on the chip to desolder it?

Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: why do you feel that it is a hardware issue and not a software issue?

Comment: @jsotola the same software works on the PCF8574 standalone board